# How to properly emit and use class?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit, system.reflection

I am facing "chicken or the egg" dilemma. 
Finally, after many hours of struggling with CIL, I have created an instance of class that was generated by using `System.Reflection.Emit` & `Activator.CreateInstance()` method. However, because class is dynamic, Visual Studio is not aware of the class, so I can't really code with it. How do I make it usable and accessible to other code ?

Clarification:
I have created a dynamic class that represents content of UI `ListBox`. Users can go in, and change the content of `ListBox`, generating new class. I need to make my dynamic class to be usable by rest of the application, that is not really aware of this new type/class.

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Vague questions get vague answers.  Give us some real details and we can give some real answers.  (If you don't want to show your code, maybe the UI where you build the object -- this might make clear what you are doing.)

Comment: How do you plan to use the class? You can consider implementing an interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make it available statically. You need to use some kind of dynamic access. Or, make the class implement an interface and cast instances of that class to the respective interface type.

A very easy solution is to use `dynamic` if member names are statically known.